# SMTP mail only sends internally

Tags: c#, winforms, email, smtp, gmail

I've got a c# function that sends emails from the win app to me via SMTP from a gmail account.

It works, but only if the FROM parameter is internal.

When I add an external address, it runs without errors, but the email never arrives in my mailbox.

I've noticed several posts on this site with similar issues, but the difference with most seems that everyone else gets some kind of error message.

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
using (SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient(smtp.gmail.com))
{
    mail.From = new MailAddress("you@myGoogleDomain.com"); //This works
    //mail.From = new MailAddress("me@somewhere.com"); //This does not work
    mail.To.Add("recipient@myGoogleDomain.com");
    mail.Subject = "Mail Subject";
    mail.Body = mailBody;
    mail.ReplyTo = new MailAddress("me@myGoogleDomain.com");
    mail.CC.Add(new MailAddress("me@myGoogleDomain.com")); 
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    SmtpServer.Port = 587; //I've also tried 465
    //SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false; //This does not make a difference.
    SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myaccount@myGoogleDomain.com", "Pass123");
    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true; //I've also tried false

    //Add attachments
    ...    

    //Send the mail
    SmtpServer.Send(mail);
}
```

MORE INFORMATION: I notice that the emails sits in the myaccount@myGoogleDomain.com 'Sent' box.  Just no mails coming through to recipient@myGoogleDomain.com.

Comment: How do you expect to send email from google smtp with email from another domain, which uses another smtp server ?

Comment: gmail doesn't allow you to specify a "From" email address, or at least it didn't when I was trying to do it 6 months ago.

Comment: @mybirthname: Apologies - that was due to a late edit, and I did not correct it everywhere.  My bad.  Sorry.

Comment: @ user1666620: If I don't specify I get an error that the From param must exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not really with the From param, but with the ReplyTo.  Since both params are set from the same variable (and not strings), it did not work when it was set to outside my domain.

Removing the ReplyTo settings solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending email using Google smtp server on behalf of your account in Google. You can't use Google smtp with non-google account to **From**. Even if you are sending regular email in Gmail or other email you can't modify **From**. Same behavior in this code you posted.

Comment: Apologies - that was due to a late edit, and I did not correct it everywhere.  My bad.  Sorry.